# Why timeout occurs while sending email using nodemailer when amazon ec2 server is used

Tags: node.js, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer to send email from ec2 server
but it is getting timeout

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var smtpConfig =   {
                     service : 'Gmail',
                     secure : true,
                     auth   : {
                        user: 'adminemail@gmail.com',
                        pass: 'password'
                    }
                };
var smtpTransport  =   nodemailer.createTransport(smtpConfig);

smtpTransport.sendMail({
      from    : '"Admin" < adminemail@gmail.com >',
      to      : 'user@gmail.com',
      subject : 'click on link',
      html    : 'Please click on link'
   }, 
   function(err, res){
            if(err){
                console.log("email send error",err);
            }else{
                console.log("On Email Send Success : ", res);
            }
});
```

The above code is working fine on localhost but when i tried on live server running on EC2, it is getting timeout

email send error { [Error: Connection timeout] code: 'ETIMEDOUT' }

Please suggest a way to modify the code

Comment: What about setting `port: 465` or `port: 587` inside `smtpConfig`?   EC2 heavily [throttles](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-port-25-throttle/) port 25 (presumably, since you aren't setting it, that's what's being used by default) for obvious reasons, but not the other ports, which are more correct anyway.  Does that help?

Comment: I also checked with port 465 and host 'smtp.gmail.com'

Comment: Same issue us occuring, email sent is successful on localhost only

Comment: Is there any setup i need to do on amazon route 53 for email

Comment: Nothing is needed in Route 53 in order to send outgoing email through Gmail.  Have you confirmed that this instance actually has outbound connectivity, using standard command line tools?

Comment: Got the error. port 465 was not enabled on EC2

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply